# Scheduled automatic FTP

Tags: ftp, vsftpd, file-download

We receive stock inventory updates from our 7 distributors every day in an FTP download. How can I set up a scheduled to pull the CSV file from each distributors FTP daily into one folder? For example every day at 8:00 AM, the FTP would automatically download the updated inventory file from our distributors FTP and place the updated file in the same folder.

I've tried everything and haven't had any luck, I have tried doing this using the following software, WinSCP, GoodSync, FileZilla, CyberDuck, FlashFXP, FTP Voyager, & Ipswitch

however, maybe I am doing something wrong so any advice or recommendation would be greatly appreciated

Comment: TurboFTP claims to have this feature, although I've never tried it. https://www.tbsoftinc.com/turboftp/schedule-file-transfer.html

Comment: I'm assuming you're running Windows since you mentioned WinSCP... have you considered creating a simple script and then creating a task in Task Scheduler to run the script at a certain time, or times, every day?  I believe WinSCP supports CLI, but if not, [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) does _(if needing to utilize CAC certs or smart cards, utilize [PuTTY-CAC](https://risacher.org/putty-cac/))_.

Comment: Looks like WinSCP supports it too https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule

Comment: I believe you can give WinSCP a script to execute, and so create a scheduled task to call WinSCP+ftp-script

Answer (score 0):

Just write a simple download script using your favorite scriptable FTP client. And then schedule it using Windows Task Scheduler.

As you already have WinSCP, you can use it.
See [WinSCP guide to scheduling file transfers to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

WinSCP can even [generate the script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) for you.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*